# When trying To Enter BIOS GNU GRUB Screen Appears

Tags: grub2, bios

I was trying to change my boot device on Ubuntu, but when I hold <kbd>F2</kbd> (the key to enter my BIOS) Ubuntu GNU GRUB appear. I would like to know how to enter my BIOS so I can continue changing my boot device.

Comment: There should be a message at the beginning of the boot process before GRUB appears.

Comment: I have a hack if you cant get in, in time. Unplug your boot device. you will then get prompted to enter the BIOS

Comment: Ubuntu definitely didn't replace your BIOS/firmware with Grub. So this is not related to Ubuntu and not reproducible (e.g. poor description and not useful to other users) either. Have a look in the manual of your mainboard or computer to find proper instructions.

Answer (score 15):

For those that might still stumble on this problem, the solution is:

When you start your PC, hold <kbd>ESC</kbd>, or you can hold <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then start the PC, doesn't matter.
A menu will appear. From there you can select which device to boot or to go into BIOS.

Answer (score 9):

If you are to boot from a dvd or usb you can press 'c' at grub menu for a console then type exit and hit enter. It will boot on your dvd or usb. I was completely mad with this issue until I found this workaround.

Comment: Use `quit` for older versions of GRUB (0.9x in my case).

Comment: Or use `exit` to get out of grub prompt

Answer (score 8):

On a modern machine, from the `grub>` prompt use the command `fwsetup` to get back into your firmware setup (UEFI or BIOS config screen).

```
grub> fwsetup
```

Nothing else seems to get the attention of UEFI or grub during boot! Once in the UEFI setup you can then rearrange the boot order to put a working OS before grub, or drop to a UEFI shell to fix up your boot files.

Comment: This is the real answer. I couldn't get my boot menu or my bios to open with any key combos. This worked first try.

Answer (score 4):

On clicking the *Power button*, hold down <kbd>ESC</kbd> and continue to tap <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Or, in case that <kbd>F2</kbd> is linked to your <kbd>Fn</kbd>:
On clicking the *Power button*, hold down <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> and continue to tap <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You should not press and hold, you need to press it repeatedly until the BIOS shows up on the screen.

If that does not happen F2 is not the right key for your system (it depends on the maker and model of your computer).

Comment: If F2 doesn't work, try the `Del` key. Hit it repeatedly during power-up.

Comment: I am no novice and I did it tens of times(starting the BIOS or the boot menu). Since Grub 2.0 the BIOS doesn't want to load any more. F12 was for the boot menu and Del for BIOS, none work. I can press any button and it will still load GRUB.

Comment: You are failing to think GRUB has anything to do with it, remove your hard disk from your computer (note, GRUB lives there) and you will get the same results...

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it does not seem to have a fully working answer. Here's my try.

The cause of the problem is a combination of BIOS not having initialized the keyboard (along with other legacy USB devices) *and* GRUB being unable to use it properly.

The solution is:

1. **Unplug your boot drive** completely;
2. Try finding the most generic keyboard (in my case, I failed to proceed with a fancy multimedia keyboard, even when following this instruction). A standard 101/104-button keyboard would be the best; you need it only once;
3. Try plugging in your keyboard directly to USB ports (unplug your USB hosts if any);
4. Try different USB ports, preferably not USB3.0 (blue) ones;
5. Press BIOS setup key (<kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or whatever your motherboard uses);
6. In BIOS **disable Fast Boot**.

This will make your boot process slower, but GRUB will be able to see your USB keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be caused by the fact that one has `acpi=off` option in your grub.

To fix it:

- change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable value from `quiet splash acpi=off` to `quiet splash reboot=bios` in your `/etc/default/grub` file
- then please do `sudo update-grub`

Now you will be able to enter bios

However to make Ubuntu bootable again after you've change everything you needed in BIOS you should state `quiet splash acpi=off` in grub boot option (to enter it from GNU GRUB menu just navigate to your boot option (I guess it is Ubuntu) and press <kbd>e</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

Took me quite a while to got it. And it is very frustrating. On my end, I kept on hitting <kbd>F2</kbd> (whatever key you need to press). Then the GRUB menu list shows up.

I hit <kbd>C</kbd> to go to console, then I type in `reboot`.

It will restart the system but this time, it will read the function key that you expect.

Answer (score 0):

When the start button press the continues press <kbd>ESC</kbd> button and pressing the <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>.

Then the BIOS is open.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and fixed it accidentally. I restarted my computer and before letting anything happen, I held <kbd>F2</kbd> , <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd>. Pretty sure one of them did the job, but I don't know which one.

I hope this works for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am repeating the answer by [Bruno Pereira](https://askubuntu.com/a/318847/559492) because it was the secret.

**DO NOT HOLD <kbd>F2</kbd> but keep press & release <kbd>F2</kbd>.**

By keep holding <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, etc, whenever HOLDING the keys, never went into the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try simultaneously keep pressing and release <kbd>F2</kbd> button, if its not work then try <kbd>F1</kbd> button if still not then try <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> its all about depends on your BIOS version. Mine is Bios - 3.1 - and key is <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you restart the computer without letting it rest, Grub will start up faster each time, overtaking the Bios start up menu.

You need to cause Grub to delay starting up.
Discharging the computer worked a treat!

**PC: Power off, unplug then hold the power button for 20 seconds to drain any remaining power.
Plug it back in, power it back up and Grub will delay starting as if your computer has been switched off for weeks, so it won't completely overtake your BIOS menu. This will give you ample chance to access your BIOS menu. If you miss it, you'll need to unplug and discharge your computer again.**

*Laptops: Discharge by removing the battery and holding the power button for 20 seconds.*